# Unable to access unsecured https with selenium using browsermob proxy

Tags: selenium, https, proxy, selenium-chromedriver, browsermob

I'm trying to embed browsermob proxy with my selenium (chrome) framework for UI automated testing in order to intercept responses and other networking.

Description :

Selenium webdriver using browsermob proxy and it works just fine - HTTP and secured HTTPS URL's are OK. When I'm trying to navigate to unsecured HTTPS URL I get this chrome error:
ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED

Here's my python code:

```
class Browser(object):
    display = None
    browser = None

    def __init__(self, implicitly_wait_seconds=10, is_visible=True, display_size=None, browser_name='chrome'):
        if not is_visible:
            self.display = Display(display_size)
        self.server = Server('/home/erez/Downloads/browsermob-proxy-2.1.4/bin/browsermob-proxy')
        self.server.start()
        self.proxy = self.server.create_proxy()
        self.capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
        self.proxy.add_to_capabilities(self.capabilities)
        self.proxy.new_har("test", options={'captureHeaders': True, 'captureContent': True})
        self.start_browser(display_size, implicitly_wait_seconds, browser_name)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, _type, value, trace):
        self.close()

    def start_browser(self, display_size, implicitly_wait_seconds=10, browser_name='chrome'):
        if browser_name == 'chrome':
            chrome_options = Options()
            # chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
            chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["ignore-certificate-errors"])
            chrome_options.add_argument("--ssl-version-max")
            chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
            chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % self.proxy.proxy)
            chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
            chrome_options.add_argument('--allow-insecure-localhost')
            chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests')
            self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/chromedriver",
                                            chrome_options=chrome_options, desired_capabilities=self.capabilities)
            self.browser.implicitly_wait(implicitly_wait_seconds)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also call create_proxy with trustAllServers as argument:

```
self.proxy = self.server.create_proxy(params={'trustAllServers':'true'})
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem for SSL proxying using BrowserMob Proxy. For this you have to install a certificate in your browser that has been defined in this [link](https://github.com/Corefinder89/browsermob-proxy)

Go to the bottom of the document, and you will see a section called "SSL support". Install the ca-certificate-rsa.cer in your browser and there would be no issue in SSL proxying anymore.

Comment: This didnt work for me. The solution given below by opsec of using REST works.

Answer (score 3):

If installing Browsermobs/test servers certificates won't do the job, like in my case, not the most elegant way, but gets the job done:

You are able to bypass ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED error by passing a trustAllServers-parameter to the proxy instance, which will disable the certificate verification for upstream servers. Unfortunately, for as far as I know, this functionality has not been implemented in the Browsermobs Python wrapper.

However, you can start the proxy with the parameter via Browsermobs REST API (see section REST API @ https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy/blob/master/README.md). In case of Python, Requests might be the way to go.

Here's a snippet:

```
import json
import requests
from browsermobproxy import Server
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# Start the proxy via python
server = Server('/path_to/bin/browsermob-proxy')
server.start()

# Start proxy instance with trustAllServers set to true, store returned port number
r = requests.post('http://localhost:8080/proxy', data = {'trustAllServers':'true'})
port = json.loads(r.text)['port']

# Start Chromedriver, pass on the proxy
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=localhost:%s' % port)
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path_to/selenium/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)

# Get a site with untrusted cert
driver.get('https://site_with_untrusted_cert')
```

Also, if you need to access HAR-data, you'll need to do that also trough the REST API:

```
requests.put('http://localhost:8080/proxy/%s/har' % port, data = {'captureContent':'true'})

r = requests.get('http://localhost:8080/proxy/%s/har' % port)
```

Of course, since you're disabling safety features, this parameter should be used for limited testing purposes only.

Answer (score 3):

Try use this

```
self.capabilities['acceptSslCerts'] = True
```